# What does this if-statement do?: if($pages=' ') {}

Tags: php, pagination

This is an excerpt [from a tutorial](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin) on how to create pagination for an blogpost overview page.

What does the first part `if($pages == ''` *exactly* do?

> ***Quote from tutorial:*** Now we know which page we are currently viewing, but we also need to know how many pages we got. We are still asuming that we are not using a custom loop and that the $pages variable (dont mix up with $paged) was not set when we called the script. If thats the case we can once again  make use of a global variable to get that number:

```
if($pages == '')
{
    global $wp_query;
    $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if(!$pages)
    {
        $pages = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$pages` is an optional parameter. 
If not set, `$pages` will equal an empty string. 
So `if($pages == '')` checks to see if that parameter has been set.

In this call, the parameter has not been set:  `kriesi_pagination();`
In this call, the parameter *has* been set: `kriesi_pagination(5);`

In the tutorial link that you posted, read this section again, the part that starts

> As you can see we got 2 optional parameters to pass:

Comment: so the if statement runs because $pages has not been set hence beeing `==` to an empty string a.k.a. `''`

Comment: Yes that is correct